# Why does `cp -a . /dir` copy contents instead of directory?

Tags: shell, directory, cp

I wanted to copy a directory that I was presently in. I tried `cp -a . ~/xyz`

It copied the contents of the directory, yet this worked: `cp -a "$(pwd)" ~/xyz`
*[As desired, this copied the directory wrapping the contents as well.]*

Dot seemed to be doing what Splat would do... Why doesn't `.` work?

Comment: You mean you only want copy directory, but it copy directory and its content?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying question. I wanted the whole directory and contents copied (not just the contents).

Comment: This is much like specifying `cp -a * ~/xyz`; if you specified `cp -a ../directory ~xyz` the command would work as expected.

Comment: Indeed it would, yet it seems intuitive to say 'this directory--using its name' rather than to say 'my parent -- using subdirectory of name...'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It did that because `.` isn't a name that can be used to create a subdirectory.

`cp -a . ~/xyz` copies `./file1` to `~/xyz/./file1`, `./file2` to `~/xyz/./file2`, etc.  But `~/xyz/./file1` and `~/xyz/file1` are the same, so the effect is to copy the contents of the current directory to `~/xyz`.

You can see this if you add the `--verbose` option to `cp` to display each pathname as it's copied:

```
$ cp -av . ../foo/
‘./file1’ -> ‘../foo/./file1’
‘./file2’ -> ‘../foo/./file2’
```

One notable difference between `.` and `*` here is that `cp -a . /dir` will copy hidden files, unlike `*` (which doesn't match hidden files).

`~` and `*` are shell metacharacters, which means they're expanded by the shell before `cp` sees them.  On the other hand, `.` is an ordinary directory entry (that just happens to point at the directory that contains it).  It would be possible for `cp` to contain code that detects when `.` is the source of a recursive copy and substitute the name of the directory, but it doesn't, probably because nobody thought it was important.

Also, what name should it use?  That's simpler for directories than files, because filesystems generally don't allow multiple hard links to a directory (except for `.` and `..` entries).  But that doesn't consider symbolic links.  Modern shells generally track when you enter a directory via a symbolic link, and reflect that in `pwd`.

Comment: I thought that might have something to do with it. Since '.' is 'this directory', I also thought it would use 'the name of this directory.' I just checked and `echo .` does not expand the way the `echo ~` and `echo *` does...

Comment: @dvdrtrgn `.` is not an expansion, it's a hard link.

Comment: So the best answer so far is as @cjm posited, "nobody thought it was important." Since `.` is a link to the current directory that `cp` has liberty to determine whether that means "point to container" or "point to each item of contents". In hindsight it may be rather trivial to obtain the name of directory from the path. But that just isn't how it always worked. I figured someone would answer "zsh does it" or offer an alias work-around.